# Alfresco Activiti document not getting saved

Tags: activiti, alfresco-enterprise

We have Alfresco Activiti workflow in place since last 3 years. However sometimes users are not able to save the document back when they open it in the Microsoft Word.

We tried to clear the Microsoft Office Cache, logged out user and login again but still seeing the same issue. Users are able to edit document in different workflow but only this document is having this issue.

Are there any logs that I can enable to see when the document is not getting saved successfully ?

[image]

**Alfresco Process Services (powered by Activiti) v1.11.1**

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where you are storing documents? Activiti logs should show useful information.

Comment: Hi,
There are no logs in the log file. The documents are being stored on the shared drive.